# Unable to crawl some href in a webpage using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tabpage

I am currently crawling a web page using Python 3.4 and bs4 in order to collect the match results played by Serbia in Rio2016. So the url [here](http://rio2016.fivb.com/en/volleyball/women/teams/srb-serbia#wcbody_0_wcgridpadgridpad1_1_wcmenucontent_3_Schedule) contains links to all the match results she played, for example [this](http://rio2016.fivb.com/en/volleyball/women/7168-serbia-italy/post).

Then I found that the link is located in the html source like this:

```
<a href="/en/volleyball/women/7168-serbia-italy/post" ng-href="/en/volleyball/women/7168-serbia-italy/post">
    <span class="score ng-binding">3 - 0</span>
</a>
```

But after several trials, this `href="/en/volleyball/women/7168-serbia-italy/post"` never show up. Then I tried to run the following code to get all the href from the url:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Countryr = requests.get('http://rio2016.fivb.com/en/volleyball/women/teams/srb-serbia#wcbody_0_wcgridpadgridpad1_1_wcmenucontent_3_Schedule')
countrySoup = BeautifulSoup(Countryr.text)

for link in countrySoup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Then a strange thing happened. The `href="/en/volleyball/women/7168-serbia-italy/post"` is not included in the output at all.

I found that this href is located in one of the tab pages `href="#scheduldedOver"`  in side this url, and it is controlled by the following HTML code:

```
<nav class="tabnav">
    <a href="#schedulded" ng-class="{selected: chosenStatus == 'Pre' }" ng-click="setStatus('Pre')" ng-href="#schedulded">Scheduled</a>
    <a href="#scheduldedLive" ng-class="{selected: chosenStatus == 'Live' }" ng-click="setStatus('Live')" ng-href="#scheduldedLive">Live</a>
    <a href="#scheduldedOver" class="selected" ng-class="{selected: chosenStatus == 'Over' }" ng-click="setStatus('Over')" ng-href="#scheduldedOver">Complete</a>
</nav>
```

Then how should I get the href using BeautifulSoup inside a tab page?

Comment: You won't find that url in source code because data is coming from different url - http://rio2016.fivb.com/en/api/volley/matches/WOG2016/en/user/team/3017 . In order to construct that url please see `data-serviceteammatches=` in source code

Comment: Yeah. It because your html doesn't have this info <a ng-href="{{match.Url}}">
You can see it by `print Countryr.text`. Link above comment is the way to get the url.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So now I get the correct url, and seems it is only a plain text file. Is that mean beautifulsoup is done here and I need to use other search string function to get the information inside?

I have tried the following and seems the `matchSoup` is just a long string without any class separating it
`Matchr = requests.get('http://rio2016.fivb.com' + linkUrl)
matchSoup =  BeautifulSoup(Matchr.text)

print(matchSoup.text)`

Comment: No need to use `Beautifulsoup` here, I suggest you to use yaml or json module,

Comment: Thanks @akashkarothiya ! I can now get the link I want.

Comment: @Benson welcome and good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is created dynamically, if you look at the actual source you can see [Angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02) templating.

You can still get all the info in json format by mimicking an ajax call, in the source yuuuuou can also see a div like:

```
<div id="AngularPanel" class="main-wrapper" ng-app="fivb"
data-servicematchcenterbar="/en/api/volley/matches/341/en/user/lives"
data-serviceteammatches="/en/api/volley/matches/WOG2016/en/user/team/3017"
data-servicelabels="/en/api/labels/Volley/en" 
data-servicelive="/en/api/volley/matches/WOG2016/en/user/live/">
```

Using the `data-servicematchcenterbar` href will give you all the info:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin

r = requests.get('http://rio2016.fivb.com/en/volleyball/women/teams/srb-serbia#wcbody_0_wcgridpadgridpad1_1_wcmenucontent_3_Schedule')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

base = "http://rio2016.fivb.com/"

json = requests.get(urljoin(base, soup.select_one("#AngularPanel")["data-serviceteammatches"])).json()
```

In  json you will see output like:

```
{"Id": 7168, "MatchNumber": "006", "TournamentCode": "WOG2016", "TournamentName": "Women's Olympic Games 2016",
        "TournamentGroupName": "", "Gender": "", "LocalDateTime": "2016-08-06T22:35:00",
        "UtcDateTime": "2016-08-07T01:35:00+00:00", "CalculatedMatchDate": "2016-08-07T03:35:00+02:00",
        "CalculatedMatchDateType": "user", "LocalDateTimeText": "August 06 2016",
        "Pool": {"Code": "B", "Name": "Pool B", "Url": "/en/volleyball/women/results and ranking/round1#anchorB"},
        "Round": 68,
        "Location": {"Arena": "Maracanãzinho", "City": "Maracanãzinho", "CityUrl": "", "Country": "Brazil"},
        "TeamA": {"Code": "SRB", "Name": "Serbia", "Url": "/en/volleyball/women/teams/srb-serbia",
                  "FlagUrl": "/~/media/flags/flag_SRB.png?h=60&w=60"},
        "TeamB": {"Code": "ITA", "Name": "Italy", "Url": "/en/volleyball/women/teams/ita-italy",
                  "FlagUrl": "/~/media/flags/flag_ITA.png?h=60&w=60"},
        "Url": "/en/volleyball/women/7168-serbia-italy/post", "TicketUrl": "", "Status": "Over", "MatchPointsA": 3,
        "MatchPointsB": 0, "Sets": [{"Number": 1, "PointsA": 27, "PointsB": 25, "Hours": 0, "Minutes": "28"},
                                    {"Number": 2, "PointsA": 25, "PointsB": 20, "Hours": 0, "Minutes": "25"},
                                    {"Number": 3, "PointsA": 25, "PointsB": 23, "Hours": 0, "Minutes": "27"}],
        "PoolRoundName": "Preliminary Round", "DayInfo": "Weekend Day",
        "WeekInfo": {"Number": 31, "Start": 7, "End": 13}, "LiveStreamUri": ""},
```

You can parse whatever you need from those.

Comment: thanks @padraic ! It is very clear and now I can get the link.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help now I can get the correct url. It is a good learning experience for me. Thanks a lot :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

Countryr = requests.get('http://rio2016.fivb.com/en/volleyball/women/teams/srb-serbia#wcbody_0_wcgridpadgridpad1_1_wcmenucontent_3_Schedule')
countrySoup = BeautifulSoup(Countryr.text)

for link in countrySoup.find_all('div', {'id': 'AngularPanel'}):
    linkUrl = link.get('data-serviceteammatches')

json = requests.get('http://rio2016.fivb.com' + linkUrl).json()

for item in json:
    print(item.get('Url'))
```

output:

```
/en/volleyball/women/7168-serbia-italy/post
/en/volleyball/women/7172-serbia-puerto rico/post
/en/volleyball/women/7177-usa-serbia/post
/en/volleyball/women/7181-china-serbia/post
/en/volleyball/women/7187-serbia-netherlands/post
/en/volleyball/women/7195-russia-serbia/post
/en/volleyball/women/7198-serbia-usa/post
/en/volleyball/women/7200-china-serbia/post
```