# List links of xls files using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve a list of downloadable `xls` files on a website.
I'm a bit reluctant to provide full links to the website in question.
Hopefully I'm able to provide all necessary details all the same.
If this is useless, please let me know.

[Download .xls files from a webpage using Python and BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632838/download-xls-files-from-a-webpage-using-python-and-beautifulsoup) is a *very* similar question, but the details below will show that the solution most likely will have to be different since the links on that particular site are tagged with a `href` anchor:

[image]

And the ones I'm trying to get are not tagged the same way.

---

On the webpage, the files that are available for downloading are listed like this:

[image]

A simple mousehover gives these further details:

[image]

I'm following the setup [here](https://pythonspot.com/extract-links-from-webpage-beautifulsoup/) with a few changes to produce the snippet below that provides a list of *some* links, but not to any of the `xls` files:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

def getLinks(url):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    links = []

    for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
        links.append(link.get('href'))

    return links

links1 = getLinks("https://SOMEWEBSITE")
```

A further inspection using `ctrl+shift+I` in Google Chrome reveals that those particular links do not have a `href` anchor tag, but rather a `ng-href` anchor tag:

[image]

So I tried changing that in the snippet above, but with no success.

And I've tried different combinations with `e.compile("^https://")`, `attrs={'ng-href'` and `links.append(link.get('ng-href'))`, but still with no success.

So I'm hoping someone has a better suggestion!

---

EDIT - Further details

It seems it's a bit problematic to read these links directly.
When I use `ctrl+shift+I` and the `Select an element in the page to inspect it Ctrl+Shift+C`, this is what I can see when I hover over one of the links listed above:

[image]

And what I'm looking to extract here is the information associated with the `ng-href` tag. But If I right-click the page and select Show Source, the same tag only appears once along with som metadata(?):

[image]

And I guess this is why my rather basic approach is failing in the first place.

I'm hoping this makes sense to some of you.

Comment: try view the page source, is the `.xls` file exist?

Comment: @ewwink I think so. All I have to do is click the link and it starts downloading.

Comment: when viewing the source do you find `.xls`? if not you need to use `selenium` or capture XHR request URL

Comment: @ewwink No, I don't see `.xls` in the source. Any suggestions on a `selenium` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://.....')

# wait max 15 second until the links appear
xls_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@ng-href, ".xls")]'))
# Or
# xls_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, ".xls")]'))

links = []
for link in xls_links:
    url = "https://SOMEWEBSITE" + link.get_attribute('ng-href')
    print(url)
    links.append(url)
```

---

Assume `ng-href` is not dynamically generated, from your last image I see that the URL is not starts with `https://` but the slash `/` you can try with regex URL contains `.xls`

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'ng-href': re.compile(r"\.xls")}):
    xls_link = "https://SOMEWEBSITE" + link['ng-href']
    print(xls_link)
    links.append(xls_link)
```

Comment: That didn't work on my end, but I think the answers so far are on the right track. I've added some more details in the question.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to implement your suggestion, but I'm having problems running Selenium and adding chromedriver.exe to PATH. So I'm going to have to sort these things out first

Comment: you can pass it as parameter `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the data you are trying to crawl is created dynamically: `ng-href` is one of AngularJs's constructs. You could try using Google Chrome's Network inspection as you already did (`ctrl+shift+I`) and see if you can find the url that is queried (open the network tab and reload the page). The query should typically return a JSON with the links to the xls-files.

There is a thread about a similar problem here. Perhaps that helps you: [Unable to crawl some href in a webpage using python and beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077890/unable-to-crawl-some-href-in-a-webpage-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)